# All fields in database updated at once using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a form that comes from a link in a table that should just update one record in my database.  When I changed some details in the table and pressed my submit button it changed all of my fields in the database and not just the one I wanted to change.  Below is my form code and also the table that is being edited.

Edit user code

```html
<?php

 // since this form is used multiple times in this file, I have made it a function that is easily reusable
 function renderForm($userID, $username, $password, $telephone, $address1, $town, $postcode, $forename, $surname, $email, $error)
 {
 ?>
 <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
 <html>
 <head>
 <title>Edit User</title>
 </head>
 <body>
 <?php 
 // if there are any errors, display them
 if ($error != '')
 {
 echo '<div style="padding:4px; border:1px solid red; color:red;">'.$error.'</div>';
 }
 ?> 
 
 <form action="" method="post">
 <input type="hidden" name="userID" value="<?php echo $userID; ?>"/>
 <div>
 <p><strong>ID:</strong> <?php echo $userID; ?></p>
 <strong>Username: </strong> <input type="text" name="username" value="<?php echo $username; ?>"/><br/>
 <strong>Password: </strong> <input type="text" name="password" value="<?php echo $password; ?>"/><br/>
 <strong>Telephone: </strong> <input type="text" name="telephone" value="<?php echo $telephone; ?>"/><br/>
 <strong>Address: </strong> <input type="text" name="address1" value="<?php echo $address1; ?>"/><br/>
 <strong>Town: </strong> <input type="text" name="town" value="<?php echo $town; ?>"/><br/>
 <strong>Postcode: </strong> <input type="text" name="postcode" value="<?php echo $postcode; ?>"/><br/>
 <strong>Forename: </strong> <input type="text" name="forename" value="<?php echo $forename; ?>"/><br/>
 <strong>Surname: </strong> <input type="text" name="surname" value="<?php echo $surname; ?>"/><br/>
 <strong>Email: </strong> <input type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo $email; ?>"/><br/>

 <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Edit details">
 </div>
 </form> 
 </body>
 </html> 
 <?php
 }



 // connect to the database
 include "config.php";
 
 // check if the form has been submitted. If it has, process the form and save it to the database
 if (isset($_POST['submit']))
 { 
 // confirm that the 'id' value is a valid integer before getting the form data
 if (is_numeric($_POST['userID']))
 {
 // get form data, making sure it is valid
 $userID = $_POST['userID'];
 $username = $_POST['username'];
 $password = $_POST['password'];
 $telephone = $_POST['telephone'];
 $address1 = $_POST['address1'];
 $town = $_POST['town'];
 $postcode = $_POST['postcode'];
 $forename = $_POST['forename'];
 $surname = $_POST['surname'];
 $email = $_POST['email'];
 
 // check that firstname/lastname fields are both filled in
 if ($username == '' || $password == '' || $telephone == '' || $address1 == '' || $town == '' || $postcode == '' || $forename == '' || $surname == '' || $email == '' )
 {
 // generate error message
 $error = 'ERROR: Please fill in all required fields!';
 
 //error, display form
 renderForm($userID, $username, $password, $telephone, $address1, $town, $postcode, $forename, $surname, $email, $error);
 }
 else
 {
 // save the data to the database
  $query = $db->prepare("UPDATE user SET username='$username', password='$password', telephone='$telephone', address1='$address1', town='$town', postcode='$postcode', forename='$forename', surname='$surname', email='$email' ");
 $query->execute();
 
 // once saved, redirect back to the view page
 header("Location: view_user.php"); 
 }
 }
 else
 {
 // if the 'id' isn't valid, display an error
 echo 'Error!';
 }
 }
 else
 // if the form hasn't been submitted, get the data from the db and display the form
 {
 
 // get the 'id' value from the URL (if it exists), making sure that it is valid (checing that it is numeric/larger than 0)
 if (isset($_GET['userID']) && is_numeric($_GET['userID']) && $_GET['userID'] > 0)
 {
 // query db
 $userID = $_GET['userID'];
 $query = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM user WHERE userID=$userID");
 $query->execute();
 $dbRow = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
 
 // check that the 'id' matches up with a row in the databse
 if($dbRow)
 {
 
 // get data from db
 $username = $dbRow['username'];
 $password = $dbRow['password'];
 $telephone = $dbRow['telephone'];
 $address1 = $dbRow['address1'];
 $town = $dbRow['town'];
 $postcode = $dbRow['postcode'];
 $forename = $dbRow['forename'];
 $surname = $dbRow['surname'];
 $email = $dbRow['email'];
 
 
 // show form
 renderForm($userID, $username, $password, $telephone, $address1, $town, $postcode, $forename, $surname, $email, '');
 }
 else
 // if no match, display result
 {
 echo "No results!";
 }
 }
 else
 // if the 'id' in the URL isn't valid, or if there is no 'id' value, display an error
 {
 echo 'Error!';
 }
 }
?>
```

View user info code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="icon" href="../../favicon.ico">

    <title>Ballymena Sports</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="home2.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>

  <body>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="home2_template.html">Ballymena Sports</a>
  </div>
  
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <li><a href="admin_login.php">Administrator</a></li>
            <li><a href="logout.php">Log out</a></li>
  </ul>
  
   </div>
    </nav>
 


    <!-- Main part of homepage -->
    <div class="jumbotron">
  <div class="container">
    <h2>Users</h2>
    <p>This table shows all registered users of Ballymena Sports:</p>            
   
   <div class="table-responsive"> 
   <tbody>
    <?php 
     include "config.php"; 
     
     $query = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM user ORDER BY userID asc");
     $query->execute();
  
  
     echo "<table id='user' class='table table-bordered'>
        <tr>
        <th>User ID</th>
        <th>Username</th>
        <th>Forename</th>
        <th>Surname</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Address</th>
        <th>Town</th>
        <th>Postcode</th>
        <th>Edit User</th> 
        <th>Delete User</th>
        </tr>";
      
     while ($dbRow = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
      $userID = $dbRow['userID'];
      $username = $dbRow['username'];
      $forename = $dbRow['forename'];
      $surname = $dbRow['surname'];
      $email = $dbRow['email'];
      $address1 = $dbRow['address1'];
      $town = $dbRow['town'];
      $postcode = $dbRow['postcode'];
      // code to display information
      
    
      { echo "<tr>
      <td>$userID</td>
      <td>$username</td>
      <td>$forename</td>
      <td>$surname</td>
      <td>$email</td>
      <td>$address1</td>
      <td>$town</td>
      <td>$postcode</td>
      <td><a href='edit_user.php?userID=".$userID."'>Edit</a></td>
      <td><a href='delete_user.php?userID=".$userID."'>Delete</a></td>
       </tr>";}
    } //while
    ?> 

   </tbody>
   </div>
    </table>
  </div>
    </div>
<?php 


 if(!$_SESSION['admin_username']){
  header('location:admin_login.php'); 
  
  $name = $_SESSION['admin_username'];
 }
 
?> 

      <hr>



    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../../dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug -->
    <script src="../../assets/js/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js"></script> 
 <!-- Header and footer later to be used as include statements -->
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Too much code, but `UPDATE` without a `WHERE` condition does that. And when you prepare a statement, you do that to prevent sql injection by binding the variables to place-holders instead of injecting user input directly in your query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that your `update` statement doesn't specify a `where` clause:

```
$query = $db->prepare("UPDATE user SET username='$username', password='$password', telephone='$telephone', address1='$address1', town='$town', postcode='$postcode', forename='$forename', surname='$surname', email='$email' ");
```

You need to use the User ID to specify that you only want to update the row for this particular user:

```
$query = $db->prepare("UPDATE user SET username='$username', password='$password', telephone='$telephone', address1='$address1', town='$town', postcode='$postcode', forename='$forename', surname='$surname', email='$email' where userId=$userID");
```

You should also look into using prepared statements to guard your code from SQL injection attacks.

Comment: The funny thing is that the OP is already using a prepared statement so you might need to expand a bit...

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, that worked great.  I'll look into the prepare statements also!  Thanks